# Java BufferedReader value become null

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm using following code to get response from the API.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("bf.readLine() - " + bf.readLine());

        output = bf.readLine();
        while (output != null) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
            System.out.println("output is " + output);
            resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
            resDesc = obj.getString("COUNT");
        }
```

I can return bf.readLine() response as follows.

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"COUNT":"0"}]}
```

Problem is when I assign the `bf.readLine()` to String and check the value, it becomes null. Why bf.readLine() shows as null (gives null point exception) even it return the value from API.

Comment: why calling `bf.readLine()` twice?

Comment: What does the API say a `null` return value means? What does this mean in context of the code?

Comment: Every time you call `readLine()` it moves ahead. Once you run out of lines to read, `readLine()` returns null which causes the _NullPointerException_ .

Comment: I don't see where you would get an NPE, which line is giving you that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

String output = null;

        while ((output = bf.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println("bf.readLine() value is--- - " + output );

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
            System.out.println("output is " + output);
            resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
            resDesc = obj.getString("COUNT");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and helpful for solve the problem. But There should have brackets for output = bf.readLine() . Could you please edit that one. Then someone can directly use it. ((output = bf.readLine()) != null) instead of (output = bf.readLine() != null)

Comment: Code is updated at your suggestion. Please read @SpringLearner answer to understand the flow and how i works

Answer (score 4):

The reason is you are calling readLine twice. You calling first at `System.out.println("bf.readLine() - " + bf.readLine());` and again at `output = bf.readLine();`

Modify as `output = bf.readLine();System.out.println("bf.readLine() - " + output);`

As per oracle docs[**readLine()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

*Returns:
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached*

if the end of the stream is reached then you will get null and operations on null will give [nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: could u please tell me where I have used twice? First one is for print the readLine value and second one for assign the value. is it a prolem

Comment: bf.readline() is used twice this means you calling readline method twice

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved according to your guidance.